# getting each iteration of XMLParser of a specific element

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse XML to my app. One of the tags (the last tag) is an article, with a length of 500 words (+,-).

The thing is, that the parser iterates when ever it "decides", so all i get is the currentNode at `didStartElement` and `didEndElement` (of a specific element). The problem is that I haven't found a way to handle the parser at a specific element. I could store all the "currentNodes" in a `NSMutableArray` of `NSString`, but handling it means a lot of memory, and time.

So, the question: is there a way to handle each iterate of the parser, based at the current element?

Comment: @Rob, the thing is, the element content (the article) is too long for one iterate of the parser, so it saves only the last iterate of it.
something like 1-2 lines.

Comment: Bottom line, can you clarify your question? Are you looking to grab a subset of element names for each item? Or are you looking to only grab a subset of rows from the entire XML? Or are you trying to solve the technical limitations that sometimes big fields are split up into multiple calls to `foundCharacters`?

Comment: I figure it out with a help of ahmed, who deleted he's answer-